# ui-router multi level nested Views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've a parent view/state called home under which I've three children names HomeOne, HomeTwo, HomeThree. Under HomeThree I'm trying to load a view which will be a child for two other children. When I click on the HomeThree I expect to load the Main container with two tabs, but right now when I click on it I see the template url being shown on the ui as '/app/main.html' instead of the content. Please help me this is first time i'm using states and it is clear up till when I use one level of nesting

HTML for my Home

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-class="{'active' : header.section == 'app'}">
                <a ui-sref="HomeOne.XXX">
                    <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                    HomeOne
                </a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{'active' : header.section == 'HomeTwo'}">
                <a ui-sref="HomeTwo.XXX">
                    <i class="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
                    HomeTwo
                </a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{'active' : header.section == 'HomeThree'}">
                <a ui-sref="HomeThree.main">
                    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i>
                    HomeThree
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

HomeOne | HomeTwo | HomeThree
                      Main 
                 TabOne|TabTwo

Main won't be seen physically as a menu item, it is just a container for TabOne and TabTwo

I'm having trouble creating the states for this. I've tried the below code and whenever I click on the HomeThree

```
        {
            name: 'HomeThree',
            url: '/HomeThree',
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            abstract: true
        },  
        {
            name: 'HomeThree.main',
            url:'/main',
            templateUrl: '/app/main.html'
        },
        {
            name: 'HomeThree.main.Tabone',
            url:'/Tabone',
            templateUrl: '/app/tabOne.html'
            component: tab  
        }   
        {
            name: 'HomeThree.main.TabTwo',
            url:'/TabTwo',
            templateUrl: '/app/tabTwo.html'

        }

Below is the code for my main.html

<div class="app-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="homeThree.main.TabOne">List</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="homeThree.main.TabTwo">Test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Comment: if you have nested views you will also need to have nested ui-view HTML elements.

Comment: see my edit, i've solved my problem